# Why isn't the intervalometer on my D800 working, no matter what settings I use?

Tags: nikon, camera-settings, timelapse, intervalometer, nikon-d800

I can't start the intervalometer, regardless of what settings I use. (Basic settings, 1 pic every seconds for 10 seconds)

I tried to change between A/M/S/P, AF-S/C, Single shot or continious, disabling all noise reduction/ADL, change exposure settings, Manual autofocus.... SD is empty, battery is full.

No matter what I do, Start is grayed. I can use the time-lapse function though.

Any idea what can block the function ?

Comment: I called Nikon support, we had to Reset to default, and then manually delete Custom A/B/C/D. I don't know what option in there I changed that blocked this function. I will post answer later if I find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was the option g4, by default in Video mode the shutter-release button will 'take a picture', changing it to 'Record movies' will block the intervalometer.

Comment: I can't thank you enough, this problem was driving me crazy.